# Can anybody tell the name of this part from my Renault Megane Sedan 2006 1.6 l?

Tags: transmission, renault, megane

A part in the gearbox of my 2006 Renault Megane 1.6 l broke so the service needs this part to repair it.

It's placed somewhere in the clutch, gear, cylinder system.

Problem is I dont know how is this part called so I cant search to buy it online?

How can I find out the name of the part so I can buy it online? Can anybody help?

[image][image]

Comment: Need you to give more detail. Is this an automatic or manual transmission? You wrote "*part in the gearbox*". So this is an internal part of the transmission? Can you ask the service what it is called, because "*somewhere in the clutch, gear, cylinder system*" is too vague for us to really help. Are there any markings on it? You wrote that is is broken. Is there another piece to it?

Comment: Come on, it says "fuel filter" right there on the box!

Comment: @JPhi1618 The Chevrolet fuel filter? LOL

Comment: @mirzahat that looks like a part of the clutch slave cylinder? where is the rest of it...?

Comment: Thx for replies, actually I discovered it is a membrane part in the clutch system and it needs to be replaced, @CharlieRB its a manual transmission...so I guess I have it solved! thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the exact [catalog number](https://www.google.ba/search?q=8200595252&oq=8200595252&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.22777j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) of the part.

Its a membrane in the clutch system.

Here also the [link in German](https://www.der-ersatzteile-profi.de/artikel/hydraulikanschluss-fuer-kupplung-a1057460)

I'm still not sure about the exact name but an online store told me that it is a membrane in the clutch system.

So, I guess that marks it as solved. Also, its a manual transmission issue.

My Megane will be healthy and happy again :)

Comment: Nice. Now you have to make your answer as “the answer” and this Q will be all wrapped up! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to look at a good clutch assembly diagram and find the location that the part came from. In a shop service manual for example they will usually have a reference table that lists the part number and factory part name.

Otherwise I’d recommend waiting for someone here who knows Renault specifically (or really knows transmissions and clutches) to give you pointers.

Comment: Thx for replies, actually I discovered it is a membrane part in the clutch system and it needs to be replaced, @CharlieRB its a manual transmission...so I guess I have it solved! Thanks anyway

Comment: @mirzahat Awesome! You should add your own answer so that it's marked and anyone else that may look this up see the actual answer. ;) Cheers!